# Tag statistics: how are they calculated?

Tags: discussion

I was having a glance at the statistics for a specific tag:

[image]

Considering that today is the 6th of January and "this year" is so far equivalent with "this month" I wondered if the line in the red not-quite-rectangle above is the result of someone trying to find good shorthand expressions for *"last 30 days"* and *"last 365 days"* and failing.

Comment: Not sure about this specific instance, but SE does have different notions about time ranges. As an example, the rep statistic (e.g. http://serverfault.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) uses calendar weeks, months and years, while the mod flagging statistic (which you can't see) uses rolling time periods where "last month" really means "last 30 days".